# How does the <li> items shift up and down without CSS position or margin-top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking at the CSS of the page http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD231LL/A?  if we click on the right side under "Available for pickup" for "See more stores", then an overlay appears for us to type in the zipcode, and say we type in `94112`, and press Enter, then it shows a list.

The strange thing is, when we click "Next" to see the next page of the stores, we can inspect the top row of the displayed store list, and it is just the 6th `<li>` item, being shifted up.  But I don't see any mechanism at all that uses `position: absolute`, `position: relative` with a `top` set, or even something like `margin-top: -800px`.  So the whole list of 20 `<li>` are all there, but by what mechanism can the `<li>` items be shifted up and down inside the `<ul>` like this when the Next or Prev button is clicked on?

**Update:** I found that the `scrollTop` is actually changed... but there is no scroll bar, so can `scrollTop` be used when there is no scroll bar, and during development, won't `scrollTop` easy to be confused with other CSS style?  And actually, is there pros and cons using CSS vs `scrollTop`?

Comment: why the downvote? this is a perfectly valid question about CSS / JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting solution to be honest. You are right about `scrollTop` and the reason why there's no scroll bar is because the `<ul>` has `overflow: hidden;` which prevents scrollbars from showing.

Edit:

Apparently scrollTop method is faster than using absolute positioning: http://jsperf.com/scrolltop-vs-absolute-position

Comment: so scrolling using `scrollTop` when no scroll bar is showing... I could imagine some browser may not like it, although this solution obviously works on all major browsers...

Comment: Not really, it's a fully acceptable solution - `overflow: hidden` only hides the scrollbars but you can still scroll it with javascript.